# Stripe PaymentIntent setup_future_usage to off_session for connected account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

PaymentIntent fails when using a connect account and setting `setup_future_usage` to `off_session`

**PaymentIntent creation**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$result = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create(
    array(
        "amount"=>1000,
        "currency"=>"gbp",
        "payment_method_types"=>array('card'),
        "application_fee_amount"=>100,
        "setup_future_usage"=>"off_session"
    ),
    array("stripe_account"=>"acct_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
);
print_r($result);
```

This is the uncaught error response

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'You cannot update `setup_future_usage` from off_session to on_session on a PaymentIntent when using a publishable key. When `setup_future_usage` is already set, you can only update the value from on_session to off_session.'
```

If I remove the `stripe_account` and `application_fee_amount` keys from the array I get a successful creation, meaning its something to do with connected accounts

```
Stripe\PaymentIntent Object ( [id] => pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [object] => payment_intent...
```

The stripe docs simply say the same as the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it worked the next day without any changes.

Possibly was a Stripe bug